# IIS Manager Unable to Save Connections

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-manager

Running IIS Manager on WinServer2K12 R2. I am unable to Save the connections. I ran as admin just to rule out permission issues. As you can see the Save icon is greyed out/disabled. How can I enable this?

[image: greyed_out]

Comment: What changes do you want to save? Did you create a connection to a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may not instal the "IIS Manager for Remote Administration". I suggest you could check your server installer to make sure you have install it.

Besides, I suggest you could try to download it and install it direclty by using below url:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager